# Swift image and video asset add to Fusuma

Tags: swift

I am using [Fusuma](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma) for a image video application. I need all the assets(images and videos)of the camera roll. Here PHAsset is using for picking the assets. Here only gallery image is displaying. But I want to show all the images and videos in library section. Can any one please suggest me how can I modify the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 source types for apple to retrieve the photos from:

1. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
2. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
3. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

You can read more about them here: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)

The PhotoLibrary is what you need to be accessing. If the API gives an option to access one of the two, choose it. If it doesn't, I would try to fork the repo with permission and make the change yourself. The user must give permissions to access the Library folder for you to access it, so be aware of that.